# Where to get OpenSSL binary for Android?

Tags: certificates, https

I have a Nexus 10 (unlocked & rooted) and I wanted to get the openssl binary on there so I can verify HTTPS certificates:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect <IPADDRESS>
```

However, no matter what I do I can't find a simple way of getting OpenSSL on Android so I can run the command above. I found something about 'opkg' but I couldn't get this process working. It was also incredibly complex. There is also an app called "Botbrew", but this project seems dead and doesn't work.

Anyone know how to get OpenSSL binary on my Nexus 10? At the very least, how can I view the certificate chain that Google uses when negotiating SSL handshake for the Gmail app (this is ultimately my goal)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet will be to build it from source.

There are a few StackOverflow questions that you might want to reference if you haven't already.

[How to use openSSL Library in the ANDROID application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046573/how-to-use-openssl-library-in-the-android-application?lq=1)

[How to build OpenSSL on Android/Linux ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5728828/how-to-build-openssl-on-android-linux)

[Openssl Build Issue with Android NDK r8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11856688/openssl-build-issue-with-android-ndk-r8)

The first SO has an answer linking to [a GitHub project android-external-openssl](https://github.com/fries/android-external-openssl/blob/master/README.android).  I would suggest trying to work with this code as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

The link in other answer is expired.

Built my own, for various archs:

- https://vi-server.org/pub/openssl_1.1.1_android_static_arm
- https://vi-server.org/pub/openssl_1.1.1_android_static_aarch64
- https://vi-server.org/pub/openssl_1.1.1_android_static_x86
- https://vi-server.org/pub/openssl_1.1.1_android_static_x86_64

"static" here does not mean actually static, just that libssl and libcrypto are inside.

```
SHA256 (openssl_1.1.1_android_static_aarch64) = 1bf30e1a15d309e42240cce4902d7436005c2f79973bb2e0126d4c49aa2a05bf
SHA256 (openssl_1.1.1_android_static_arm) = 87fe53abbdd68378e1497848d27fc63384dfeeaa17e38874522d21f998731c34
SHA256 (openssl_1.1.1_android_static_x86) = aa70c8a82d3f0b198aae5f26f688d4137fc87bc3bf70aa01782399b5e3e9f7f6
SHA256 (openssl_1.1.1_android_static_x86_64) = 9c3717a51cfb133a33552985f84d2eccb7c125a217d3be4c1cde1696d4410605
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://curl.haxx.se/download.html:

It seems that http://curl.haxx.se/gknw.net/7.31.0/dist-android/curl-7.31.0-rtmp-ssh2-ssl-zlib-static-bin-android.tar.gz contains an openssl binary.